# SQL JOIN three tables to obtain total values

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
adhocbills
- sequence
- invoice_number

adhocbills_lineitems
- sequence
- bill_seq
- unitprice
- quantity
- service

billing_invoices
- sequence
- invoice_number
- datetime
- sub_total
```

I want to select all rows from `billing_invoices` for a certain date range which i am doing with this query:

```
select * from billing_invoices 
where DATE(datetime) >= 'x' AND DATE(datetime) <= 'x'
```

but then i need to select the equivilent row from `adhocbills` using:

```
billing_invoices.invoice_number = adhocbills.invoice_number
```

then i need to select all rows from `adhocbills_lineitems` using:

```
adhocbills.sequence = adhocbills_lineitems.bill_seq
```

and from `adhocbills_lineitems` get the totals and group by `service`

the total i want to return from `billing_invoices.sub_total`

i tried this query, joining all tables:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(i.sequence) as counter, l.service as service, SUM(i.sub_total) as sub_total, SUM(i.total_charges) as total_charges, SUM(i.vat_amount) as vat_amount, SUM(i.grand_total) as grand_total 
FROM billing_invoices i 
LEFT JOIN adhocbills a ON a.invoice_number = i.invoice_number 
LEFT JOIN adhocbills_lineitems l ON a.sequence = l.bill_seq 
WHERE 
  i.proforma <> 'Y' 
  AND i.invoice_type = 'Invoice' 
  AND a.status = 'Completed' 
  AND DATE(i.datetime) >= '2016-09-01' 
  AND DATE(i.datetime) <= '2016-09-30' 
GROUP BY l.service 
ORDER BY grand_total DESC
```

but that is returning the incorrect values

for example, i have this data in my `adhocbills_lineitems` table so when these are grouped together by `service` so there would be 2 rows:

```
Service 1 / 50
Service 2 / 30+20 = 50
```

sample data:

adhocbills table:

```
sequence = '1'
type = 'Invoice'
invoice_number = '1234'
```

[image: adhocbills]

adhocbills_lineitems table:

```
sequence = '1'
bill_seq = '1'
unitprice = '50'
quantity = '1'
service = 'Service 1'

sequence = '2'
bill_seq = '1'
unitprice = '30'
quantity = '1'
service = 'Service 2'

sequence = '3'
bill_seq = '1'
unitprice = '20'
quantity = '1'
service = 'Service 2'
```

[image: adhocbills_lineitems]

billing_invoices table:

```
sequence = '1'
invoice_number = '1234'
sub_total = '100'
vat_amount = '20'
grand_total = '120'
datetime = '2016-09-01'
invoice_type = 'Invoice'
```

[image: billing_invoices]

so from this sample data, when the 'service' column is grouped in `adhocbills_lineitems` the result should be:

Service 1 = 50 - (made up of 1 row = 50)
Service 2 = 50 - (made up of 2 rows = 30 and 20)

Comment: sample input and sample output please.

Comment: The screenshot you attached is not of the query you showed

Comment: What is you expected result, can you add it to the question?

Comment: No screenshots thanks. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Shaharyar added expected result

Comment: Thats all? You just want the service column in final result set?

Comment: i want the sub_total summed from billing_invoices table and group by service in adhocbills_lineitems table

Comment: It will show the `sub-total = 200` for both the rows.

Comment: thats not correct

Comment: Then waht it should be? Why don't you add the complete result set in tabular form? You just added `service` column

Comment: it should be 50 for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table structure does not match select query. This answer is based on your information about relation between tables and expected output.

```
SELECT 
  l.service,
  SUM(l.unitprice) AS total
FROM 
  billing_invoices i
  LEFT JOIN adhocbills a ON a.invoice_number = i.invoice_number
  LEFT JOIN adhocbills_lineitems l ON a.sequence = l.bill_seq
WHERE 
  i.datetime BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2016-09-30'
GROUP BY
  l.service
ORDER BY
  total DESC
```

This matches your expected output. You should be summing by `unitprice`, not `sub_total` as you've mentioned in your question.

Should there by any more constraints add them to WHERE clause.

I've simplified date conditions to be able to use plain index on `datetime` field since MySQL doesn't support indexes on expressions.

Comment: looks correct, i need to select the sub_total from billing_invoices though and not the unit_price from adhocbills

Comment: I've changed the summed column accordingly.

Comment: Tired that, but that's returning incorrect values again

Comment: Add data to your question from all three tables. There must be 1:N relationship which is multiplying the sub_total column.

Comment: your first query using `SUM(l.unitprice)` returns the correct values, but i need to sum the values from `billing_invoices` instead of `adhocbills` i will do screen shots of data

Comment: adhocbills: https://postimg.org/image/apsgcgd3d
adhocbills_lineitems: https://postimg.org/image/p7pnkg4eh
billing_invoices: https://postimg.org/image/49jhmd4jt

Comment: No, no, my friend. Post it __as text__ in your question by editing it as I've suggested. This is not a free coding service. Don't make this hard for people to help you.

Comment: adding data to question now

Comment: You've specified expected output that matches `unitprice` not `sub_total`. If you sum values from `sub_total` it will take 100 and for service 1 return 100 and service 2 it would be 200 as there are 2 rows which is 2*100. You should sum by `unitprice`. I'm editing back my answer because it was correct.

Comment: as i said, the query works fine when you use `SUM(l.unitprice)` but i want to sum from the `billing_invoices` table

Comment: does it make sense?

Comment: No it doesn't make any sense unless you want the result to be 100 and 200.

Comment: thats not correct though, i want to sum the sub_total column from billing_invoices and group by service from adhocbills_lineitems table

Comment: @charlie Your requirements doesn't make any sense, re-think about it. Generate a proper tabular form of final resultset and add it to the question. I think you're confused in aggregation.